# Some problems with converting opencv c++ code into java

Tags: java, android, opencv

```
vector<Point> pointsInterest;
        Mat_<uchar>::iterator itMask= mask.begin<uchar>();//mask is a Mat
        Mat_<uchar>::iterator end= mask.end<uchar>();
        for( ; itMask!=end; ++itMask)
            if(*itMask==255)
                pointsInterest.push_back(itMask.pos());

        RotatedRect minRect = minAreaRect(pointsInterest);
```

I need java implementation of the code

Comment: what are you trying to achive with the mask ? in general, you're better off **not** trying the same in java, there are no iterators, and anything done *per pixel* is grossly slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In same time we are doing same thing! :) Few days ago i found somewhere on the Internet similar problem with solution.

Here is solution:

```
    ArrayList<Point> pointsInterestList = new ArrayList<Point>();

    for (int j = 0; j < mask.rows(); j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < mask.cols(); k++) {
            double[] pixel = mask.get(j, k);

            if (pixel[0] == 255) {
                //add Point of Mat to list of points
                Point point = new Point(k, j);
                pointsInterestList.add(point);
            }
        }
    }

    // System.out.println("PointsInteresedList: "+pointsInterestList);

    MatOfPoint2f m2fFromList = new MatOfPoint2f();
    m2fFromList.fromList(pointsInterestList); //create MatOfPoint2f from list of points
    MatOfPoint2f m2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
    m2fFromList.convertTo(m2f, CvType.CV_32FC2); //convert to type of MatOfPoint2f created from list of points


    RotatedRect minRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(m2f);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer =) Are you working at Number Plate Recognition?